# Search for chmod 777 in terminal

Tags: unix, search, permissions, chmod

I'm working with a system where a few files and maps seem to have permission 777. 
I want to change them to a more secure chmod, but I don't have a list of all the 777-files.

I could do a terminal command like `ls -l -R` , but the filesystem has thousands of files, so that's not really efficient.

Is there a query-like way to find all te files that have 777 for permission? like `ls -l -R where chmod = 777` or something, or otherwise maybe a php solution? I don't know how that would work.

Thanks!

Comment: See [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
find ./  -perm 777
```

For more information, check:

```
man find
```